# How to read special character input in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, special-characters, isinstance

In Python3, When I try to read the  input foo(1,?i:int) from console:

It gives syntax error!
It can accept other inputs such as foo(1,2,2),foo('d',0).

```html
def foo(*x):  #Multiple Argument function
  print(x)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `"?i:int"` instead of unquoted one(`?i:int`)?

Comment: No..The requirement is to read it as ?i:int, where ?: are symbols . Basically I have to give this input and then the function will check if the second parameter is int. Similarly, I should implement for str and float. Any help is greatly appreciated. @Lafexlos